# How do I use dijit.TooltipDialog on a div?

Tags: dialog, dojo

I would like to show a "drop down dialog" when I click my link/div.

So far have the following code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" djConfig="isDebug: false, parseOnLoad: true" src="lib/dojo/dojo.js">
            </script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                dojo.require("dojo.parser");
                dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");
                dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
                dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
                dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
                dojo.require("dijit.form.DropDownButton");

                dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

                    console.log("Hello");
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body class="tundra">
            <!-- Login DIV -->
            <div id="login">
                <a href="#" title="">Login Link</a>
            </div>

                <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                    <span>Username:</span>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox">
                    </div>
                    <span>Password:</span>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" type="password">
                    </div>
                    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>

            <!-- Login Button -->
            <button dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton"">
                <span>Login Button</span>
                <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                    <span>Username:</span>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox">
                    </div>
                    <span>Password:</span>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" type="password">
                    </div>
                    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </button>

        </body>
    </html>
```

How can I make my Login Link behave like Login Button? Or is there another way I can do this in Dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a nice post 
[link -> tooltips on anchors](http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/11/23/tooltips-from-anchors/)

it's not for tooltipdialogs, but it simulates it's functionality.

-or-

```
<div id="login" dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
    <a href="#" title="">Login Link</a> 
    <div id="loginDialog" dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog" style="display:none" >
        <span>Username:</span>
        <div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox">
        </div>
        <span>Password:</span>
        <div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" type="password">
        </div>
        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the link helped. Only thing now is the auto close the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Anther way to do this, is by using DropDownButton, but replacing the css attributes associated with the button with a different style that will make the button look like an anchor.